# with the TDE in Marklogic, how to conserve the position() in a TDE

Tags: marklogic

For example I have a XML file like :

```
<root>
<step>position 1 </step>
<step>position 2 </step>
<step>position 3</step>
</root>
```

the order is important because the weight of each step are different and I don't know how many step there is in the file.
In Xpath there is the `position()` function.

But with TDE if I put the context on step to create de row, the position is always 1.

I don't find a solution to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could `count()` the number of `preceding-sibling::step`:

```
1 + count(preceding-sibling::step)
```

An example:

```
let $doc := 
  <root>
    <step>position 1 </step>
    <step>position 2 </step>
    <step>position 3</step>
  </root>

let $tde:=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/root/step</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>stackoverflow</schema-name>
      <view-name>positionExample</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>name</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>.</val>
        </column> 
        <column>
          <name>position</name>
          <scalar-type>integer</scalar-type>
          <val>1 + count(preceding-sibling::step)</val></column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>

return  
  tde:node-data-extract($doc,$tde)
```

Comment: I thank that I can't use de axis with TDE XPath, it's only in the <context>?
So I don't do the test :(
Thank you !

Comment: The sample as provided above works and gives what is likely meant to be the results.